# Convert data frame column to float and perform operation in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame that contains the following that are imported as strings

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
                       'Column1':['10/1','9/5','7/4','12/3','18/7','14/2']})
```

I am tried to convert to float and do the division. The following did work well.

```
for i, v in enumerate(df3.Column1):
    df3['Column2'] = float(v[:-2]) / float(v[-1])
    print df3.Column2
```

This is the output that I am trying to achieve

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
                       'Column1':['10/1','9/5','7/4','12/3','18/7','14/2'],
                       'Column2':['10.0','1.8','1.75','4.0','2.57142857143','7.0']})
df3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work, define a function to perform the casting to float and return this, the result of which should be assigned to your new column:

```
In [10]:

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
                       'Column1':['10/1','9/5','7/4','12/3','18/7','14/2']})
def func(x):
    return float(x[:-2]) / float(x[-1])

df3['Column2'] = df3['Column1'].apply(func)
df3
Out[10]:
  Column1    Column2
0    10/1  10.000000
1     9/5   1.800000
2     7/4   1.750000
3    12/3   4.000000
4    18/7   2.571429
5    14/2   7.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

if, and ONLY IF, you do not have input/data from an untrusted source, here's a shortcut:

```
In [46]: df3
Out[46]:
  Column1
0    10/1
1     9/5
2     7/4
3    12/3
4    18/7
5    14/2

In [47]: df3.Column1.map(eval)
Out[47]:
0    10.000000
1     1.800000
2     1.750000
3     4.000000
4     2.571429
5     7.000000
Name: Column1, dtype: float64
```

But seriously...be careful with eval. [image: Good old Bobby Tables]